# Biting your cheek

Tags: shabbat, health-safety-shmira

I have a habit of biting the side of my cheek, On shabbos, would this habit be considered breaking shabbos?

Comment: Lee Gelsky, Welcome to mi.yodeya, and thanks very much for the interesting question! We'd love to have you as a fully registered member, which you can accomplish at http://mi.yodeya.com/users/login

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morsicatio_buccarum

Answer (score 3):

If you're making it bleed or bruise it could be a problem; (the labor category of "slaughtering" includes any causing of bleeding), otherwise, I don't see the issue.

Comment: It is klAcher Yad (done in an unusual way). It is also likely to be Mekalkel (no constructive purpose) unless you do it for some good reason. It is also Eino Mischaven (without intent) meaning you don't do it for the purpose of expressing blood, even though you are aware it *might* happen. If it is done unconciously, then it is also Misaseik (an unconcious act). In conclusion: ask your Rav.

Comment: @Barry, how do we rule regarding "mekalkel b'chabura"? All great points; as I said, "it could be a problem" (could be not); but if there's no bruising or bleeding, there's nothing to talk about here. Not every m.y question is so complicated.

Answer (score 2):

If you are doing it out of habit (i.e. unconsciously) then even if it makes it bleed this might be considered *misaseik* (unintentional) and **may** not be something you are guilty for doing, even though it is recommended you break the habit.